# How to deploy Node.js express server on GCP whithout `gcloud app deploy`?

Tags: node.js, express, google-compute-engine, gcloud, mern

I do not want to use the command `gcloud app deploy` to deploy my Node.js Express server.

Ideally, I want to:

1. Clone the repo on the VM Instance
2. Run `npm install`
3. Run `npm start` which will start the node server at port 5000.

What are the firewall rules for such configuration? Will I use the external IP of the VM to send the requests to my server or something else? What is the role, if any, of NGINX here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could just config the regular http and https ports on Google cloud and use nginx as a proxy to route the data on to your app.

Nginx conf example:

```
server {
listen 80;

 location / {
     proxy_pass http://yourAppAddress:5000/;
 }
}
```

Although I would recommend using Docker to deploy your application.

Comment: I did something like that and it worked! Thanks for replying!

Answer (score 1):

**To install and run Node.js express sercer on GCP instance follow these steps (tested on Debian9 VM):**

```
sudo apt update
sudo su -
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash -
apt install -y nodejs
curl -L https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh
npm install -g express-generator
logout
express myproj1
cd myproj1
npm install
npm start
```

After which you should see

```
> m1@0.0.0 start /home/wbogacz/m1
> node ./bin/www
```

**Regarding firewall - add a rule to allow TCP traffic on port 3000 to this machine; see example below;**

`gcloud compute --project=myproject firewall-rules create express_rule --direction=INGRESS --priority=1000 --network=default --action=ALLOW --rules=tcp:3000 --source-ranges=0.0.0.0/0 --target-tags=myvm`

This assumes that your instance has a tag `myvm`.

After which you should be able to go to the external IP of your VM and see in the browser page with `Welcome to Express` message.